# Wcf returns "success" just for first time and subsequent calls return "timeout"

Tags: wcf

I researched this problem but i couldn't find any useful result.
I tried to configure web.config and iis configurations (disabling cache etc.) but result is negative.
When i make request as restful using wcf, some of wcf methods works fine for everytime but some of **wcf methods work just first time returning success, subsequent calls' results return "timeout**".

When i restart iis and , i end iis worker task on the task manager and i debug wcf service, troubled methods work fine just first time.

Please help me

Thank you in advance

For Ex:

[REQUEST] localhost/Service1.svc/GetData?value=8

[RESPONSE] "You entered: 8"

GetData method already works fine

but for Arm method;

[REQUEST first] localhost/Service1.svc/Arm?pass=1234&type=2

[RESPONSE first] {"Data":true,"Error":false,"Message":"Success"}

[REQUEST subsequents] localhost/Service1.svc/Arm?pass=1234&type=2

[RESPONSE subsequents] {"Data":false,"Error":true,"Message":"Request timeout.   Please try again later"}

---Service1.svc.cs---

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetData?value={value}")]
        //stable method
        public string GetData(int value)
        {

            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "Arm?pass={pass}&type={type}")]
        //troubled method
        public ReturnType<bool> Arm(string pass, int type)
        {
            ParadoxFunctions pf = new ParadoxFunctions(pass);
            ReturnType<bool> ret = new ReturnType<bool>();

            ParadoxReturn pr = pf.ArmPanel(type);

            if (pr.Success)
            {
                ret.Error = false;
                ret.Message = pr.Message;
                ret.Data = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ret.Message = pr.Message;
            }

            return ret;
        }
     }
```

---Web.config---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
                          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="65536000"/>
                          <pages validateRequest="false" />
    <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>


    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000" transferMode="StreamedRequest">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly>

        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.28.0" newVersion="4.2.28.0"/>

      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it?

Comment: i edit my question now for you one moment.

Comment: i edited the question my friend. I hope it is enough.

Comment: It seems the timeout message is not from being unable to reach your service, but from unable to do whatever those Paradox functions are doing. Maybe you should check *them*? Can you put a breakpoint there and step through your code?

Comment: Thank you for your response my friend. I'll make it.